# Creating a new user in the API management with ADB2C

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm trying to migrate users from two instances of API management.

My users log in using an Active directory B2C instance.

When I create the user programmatically, using the REST API, via the Nodejs
SDK, it looks like I'm able to create only users whose provider is "Basic" (but not "AadB2C"):

```
const newApimUser = await apiClient.user.createOrUpdate(
  <resource group>,
  <api mgmt>,
  ulid(),
  {
    email: <user email>,
    firstName: <first name>,
    identities: [
      {
        id: userAdId,
        provider: "aadB2C" // neither "AadB2C" works here
      }
    ],
    lastName: <last name>,
    state: "active"
  }
);
```

see 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/user_createorupdate

the resulting user has

```
identities: [
      {
        id: <user email>,
        provider: "Basic"
      }
    ],
```

which prevents such new users to login using ADb2c.

Comment: Did you try to make a simple REST call to see if it's an SDK problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this happens because of a bug in the API models:

see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/3857